# Round off to decimals

Tags: decimal-expansion, rounding-error, rounding-unit

I m not sure about this problem. Pl help.         1. Roundoff this number to tenths place 87.952
2. Round off this number to hundredths place 75.195

As per me answer should be 88.0 and 75.2 for second one.  Can some one help and advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got 1. correct and 2. incorrect:

1. $88.0$
2. $75.20$

For 2., remember that you are being asked to round $75.195$ to the hundredths place, which means that you need to include the significant figure in the hundredths place.

But be careful to recognise when a $0$ is a significant figure and when it isn't: http://www.staff.vu.edu.au/mcaonline/units/numbers/numsig.html

Comment: Thanks, now I m confident about the concept